# dotnet-cli, single project that produces build configuration outputs for version ASP.NET MVC 3/4/5/6

Tags: .net, compilation, asp.net-core

I have a project that I want to support multiple versions of ASP.NET MVC.

Something like...

```
"frameworks": {
  "net451": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "5.2.*"
    }
  },
  "net451": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "4.0.*"
    }
  }
}
```

How do I manage this? Multiple `project.json` files?

- `project.mvc3.json`
- `project.mvc4.json`
- `project.mvc5.json`
- `project.mvc6.json`

Then, each product will produce `[Assembly].[MvcX].dll`?

Maybe a single `project.json` file, but use the `configurations` element? However, I don't think you can manage dependencies in this section.

Comment: I really doubt you can run MVC2-4 in an .NET CLI, as these version don't even have OWIN support and ASP.NET Core only uses principles of what Microsoft learned with Katana, so their pipelines are completely different. Also ASP.NET Core MVC isn't called MVC6 anymore for a good reason: It's not an new release based on ASP.NET MVC it's a **complete** rewrite. While the ASP.NET team made efforts to make the transition as easy as possible, they can't really be considered compatible

Comment: @DavidPine: It's the other way around. `net462` is only compatible with `net462` and **newer**, because it supports the latest features to supports fewest platforms. Using an `net462` in `net45` is absurd. The `net462` could use `Task.CompletedTask` which returns a completed task. This doesn't even exist in .NET 4.5 as it was introduced with .NET 4.6. TFM always puts gives you two choices: more features, lesser platforms. or more platforms, lesser features ;)

Comment: @Tseng, I don't think that is true. I can build a library that uses net40 using dotnet-cli. The build output is a valid .NET assembly with normal references retrieved from NuGet. I may have issues using MVC3-4-5 in an actual dotnet-cli project, but I'm pretty sure you can produce a library to be used in a normal csproj/owin-based project.

Comment: Technically yes, you can target .NET 4 from a, but you can't run a :NET 4.0 assembly in ASP.NET Core MVC. But lets do a step back: From your question it's unclear if you want to port an ASP.NET [Core] MVC application or an library? Having an MVC Application which runs on both MVC2-5 and ASP.NET Core MVC is pretty much impossible without extreme amount of preprocessor directives. But you can only target platforms (net standard, full .net framework, mono, uwp), not libraries. When such a project is compiled, you get a nuget package as result which contains different assembly for each target

Comment: @Tseng, exactly, I plan on having ```#define```s everywhere. I am only implementing a ```IViewEngine```, so it shouldn't be too bad. I make make ```project.mvc4.json```, and as a part of my build process, rename it to ```project.json``` to build multiple assemblies to target different versions of MVC.